# What is the use of reverse domain indentifier in Cordova create command

Tags: cordova

I've been playing with Cordova for a while now but haven't published any apps to any stores yet. In the Cordova `create` command I always used to specify the reverse-domain indentifier.

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Why we've to specify the `com.example.hello` and what is the use of that? Is that used any where while creating profiles/certificates in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`com.example.hello` is the package name on android apps and the bundle identifier on ios apps

it will be used to identify your app (so it makes sense to use the reverse domain so it can be identified with your website) and it has to be unique

on google play you'll be able to find your app using the package name

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.hello
```

on app store the bundle id isn't visible, but it's used internally for itunes connect and for certificates and services (development, distribution and push certificates, game center, icloud, etc)

Comment: Your reply answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: can we change it after we create the project?

Comment: Yeah, just change the value in the config.xml and run `cordova prepare` and it will be updated in the native projects. But once you submit the app to Google Play you can't change it anymore, if you change it, they will consider it as a new app

Answer (score 1):

I think as it is described inside the wikipedia article about this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) this is a thing which was created with the java platform and is still something for companys for example. They take their company name, combine it with the product name and it's finished.

So this is not a Cordova belonging topic only, it comes from Java :)